# Adding custom Role to Wordpress with custom permissions

Tags: wordpress, roles, user-roles

I'd like to add a new role to my Wordpress site. It needs more permissions than Author, but fewer than Admin. Searching the codex and Stack, I have come across a consistent method of adding this code to functions.php, but a repeated error resulted in me trying the User Role Editor plug-in.

Users under this new role need to be able to edit, see, delete, and managed all posts, categories and tags. They also must be able to manage all comments, both approved and pending. Additionally, they should have access to Discussion settings. This last bit seems to be impossible, though. I can give them the ability to manage options, but not specific options. Is there a way to grant such a specific capability?

Thanks.

Comment: No, it's not outdated. Also, there's nothing wrong with the code you posted. You have a syntax error somewhere in your `functions.php` Post a snippet of the code a few lines before and after where the error is reported. :)

Comment: Apologies for changing my post after you commented. I tried to hurry, and I provided a summary of why I changed.

Comment: No problem. The code you had was perfectly valid, though. One way you could accomplish this is to allow them the `manage_options` capability, but use actions/filters to disallow them to view things you don't want them to view ( i.e. general settings or blog name ). Should they be able to access everything under `Settings` or just the `Discussion` part?

Comment: We'd like to limit them to just the `Discussion` part of Settings, if possible.